# Exporting decion tree trained in adaboost (Graphviz)

Tags: python, tree, graphviz, decision-tree, adaboost

Over the past few week I've been using the export_graphviz to explore certain paths (root to leaf) of my trained decision tree. I wanted to see what the effect of Adaptive boosting is on my tree so I used Adaboost classifier with base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier, from scikit learn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier). Now I have put the AdaBoostClassifier as an estimator in a GridSearchCV to find the 'best hyperparameters' in terms of learning_rate and n_estimators (both parameters for AdaBoostClassifier).

```
grid_cv = GridSearchCV(AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=clf), scoring='f1', param_grid=param_grid_Ada, cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
```

After training my model I wondered if I also could see the underlying tree with the export_graphviz function (t.b.h. I could not find anything that indicated that it is or is not possible). Since AdaBoostClassifier has no attribute tree_ like the DecisonTreeClassifier I called upon the DecisionTreeClassifier like this:

```
grid_cv.best_estimator_.base_estimator_
```

This gives (an example):

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced', criterion='gini',
max_depth=15, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
min_samples_split=5, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            presort=False, random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

Now I want to get the underlying tree like for example:

```
grid_cv.best_estimator_.base_estimator_.tree_
```

It returns a None-object. So here are my questions Is it even possible to get the underlying tree object while using Adaboost & GridSearchCV together, and if so, how?

Cheers.

Comment: The tree_ returns None, because that base estimator (tree in your case) is not trained (fitted). But 50 clones of that estimator (see `n_estimators` parameter [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier)) are fitted which are then used to boost the ensemble.

Comment: You need to access `grid_cv.best_estimator_.estimators_` attribute to get the list of all fitted trees. And then you can access the `tree_` attribute of those individual trees from that list.

Comment: Hi @Vivek, thanks. A novice mistake. It seems though that the tree is a bit unreadable thanks to Adaboost but that's a concern for later:)

Comment: Yes, because the individual trees are trained on fractions of data and even that only on some features of the data.